# Redshift drop user with special character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I created by mistake in Redshift the user `mario.maria` and I'm struggling to drop it.

Usual syntax would be

```
drop user mario.maria
```

for which I get `[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`. So I try

```
drop user "mario.maria"
```

to escape the special character `.` but then I get `[42704] ERROR: User "mario.maria" does not exist`.

So here I'm asking what is the right syntax to drop user with special characters (e.g. `.`) in their name?

Comment: You can use a Visual Interface like Dbeaver , Datagrip .. , login with admin privilege and drop the user with the aid of GUI.

Comment: hey @rajorshi thanks for your input, DataGrip is actually what I'm using. I even tried to drop it from GUI but it didn't work :/ I believe it is required a specific syntax to escape the `.` character

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me in the past was to run the query from the **[Redshift Query Editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html)** with double-quotes so:

```
drop user "mario.maria"
```

Running it from my local SQL Client (DataGrip) didn't work and raised the reported issue.